Ordering MS Outlook Tasks
In MS Outlook emails can be assigned as tasks to team members. But suppose there is too much work coming in through emails, is it possible that after assigning tasks we can set priorities as numbers such that number 1 means that this job needs to be completed first before moving onto the number 2.
Further, is there a way all members in a team (we have access to MS teams also) to see what all other members have on their plates. This will help the leader to do better resource utilisation.

Please only ask a single question per post. Is the issue that you cannot add priorities, or that you cannot add priorities after a task has been assigned, or that there is no mechanism for priorities in Outlook tasks? Are you using ToDo for tasks? What research have you done regarding this?

Answer from Microsoft's documentation.
Assuming you're using ToDo for tasks, task Importance only has a binary state: Important, or Not Important. From the documentation:

Add importance
Add priority to your tasks by starring your important tasks in each
list. Once starred, you can view all of your prioritized tasks in the
important smart list. You can also sort each list by importance to
have your starred tasks automatically move to the top of the list.

As tasks can have both Tags and Categories, you may consider using either of these to assign priority. A tag of #priority1 would be top priority, for instance.

Agree with music2myear. If you need more specific priority levels, you can customize the priority field to suit your needs.
In addition, you can follow this blog to add custom priority fields to your Outlook tasks to meet your requirements: https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-add-a-custom-priority-field-to-outlook-tasks/?form=MG0AV3

Those instructions are for the old Outlook Tasks. In M365/current Office versions ToDo is the new default Tasks tool.

Thanks @Soki. Haven't tried the instructions in the blog but that seems to be what I have in mind. Only thing is that these categories will not be visible to everyone I assign tasks to. But at least for me they will be there
